# How do I initialize one object for multiple requests using spring session?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, spring-session

I have an application that requires three pieces of data.

Example:

```java
public class RequestForm {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;
    private final String c;
}
```

I would like to get requests for this object's fields one by one and initialize the object at once after storing it in the session.

A little messy example:

```java
    @PostMapping(URL+"/1")
    public ResponseEntity<String> enteredA(@RequestBody String a, HttpSession httpSession) {
        httpSession.setAttribute("a", a);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping(URL+"/2")
    public ResponseEntity<String> enteredB(@RequestBody Stirng b, HttpSession httpSession) {
        log.info("b : {} ", b);
        httpSession.setAttribute("b", b);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping(URL+"/3")
    public ResponseEntity<String> enteredC(@RequestBody String c, HttpSession httpSession) {
        log.info("c : {} ", c);
        httpSession.setAttribute("c", c);

        String a = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("a");
        String b = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("a");
        String c = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("a");
        save(new RequestForm(a, b, c);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

However, there is a strong feeling that you shouldn't do this.

I heard you can use something like @SessionAttributes.

By the way, many examples initialize one object per request and store it in the session.

Is there a way to initialize one object for multiple requests?
I am developing with Spring Boot 2.4.

please. Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need this? initializing one object for multiple requests can be done in multiple ways. Selecting the correct way depends on the purpose. If the object is specific to the user, then Session is the best way. If the object is same for all users then we should auto-wiring or creating singleton object.

Comment: Not with` @RequestBody`, you can with `@ModelAttribute`. But if you are sending JSON (judging from the `@RequestBody`) `@ModelAttribute` won;t work. Also if you are sending JSON, shouldn't you handle the multiple steps on the client side and send a single body containing everything in one go? Looks like you are trying to handle something you would handle in/on the client on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Framework supports five scopes for beans. You can use
session scope here.This scopes a bean definition to an HTTP session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Make your controller session scoped. You can then simply instantiate the object you want to store in the session scope as a member variable of the controller.

You can create a session scoped component and inject this in your controller like this :

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class RequestForm {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;
    private final String c;
}
```

Controller Class

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class SessionController
{
  @Autowired
 private RequestForm requestForm;

// Handler mapping methods
}
```